# How to combine rows in two dataframes into one dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

This is what I want to do:

Combine

```
      df1
Col1 Col2 Col3
   7    1    8
   6    2    9
   3    6    3
```

and

```
      df2
Col1 Col2 Col3
   4    6    3
   5    7    8
   9    1    2
```

into this:

```
      df3
Col1 Col2 Col3
   7    1    8
   6    2    9
   3    6    3
   4    6    3
   5    7    8
   9    1    2
```

And I'm sorry if someone has asked this already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do :

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please try to avoid answering questions that do not fit the guidelines laid out in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).